# Get info about Http Post field order

Tags: asp.net, post

Is it possible to get information about post field **order** in ASP.NET? I need to know whether some field was the last one or not.

I know I can do it through Request.InputStream, but I’m looking for a more high level solution **without manually** stream parsing.

Generally I’m doing **testing** of http post sent by my application and there is no practical usage for this in ASP.NET.

Comment: Why do you need to know if one is the last or not?

Comment: In some platforms POST request is not gotten completely after upload interruption. In this case the last field is needed for complete indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The post order is the same as they found on page.**

Make this test, the order you get them, is the one you have placed it on page.

```
foreach (string cEna in Request.Form)
{
    txtDebug.Text += "<br>" + cEna;
}
```