# How to Programatically create Multiple textboxes in an aspx page and save to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to populate textboxes (txtFirstName, txtSecondName) programatically by allowing the users to type in (say, 4) in a textbox and press the button to populate these into a panel. So if they put 2 in then they will get 2 rows of textboxes for first and last name. 
My problem is when I save I cannot get the text from these textboxes that were created on the fly. Any suggestions?

```
//button         
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        //Horizontal line
        LiteralControl hrline = new LiteralControl();
        hrline.Text = "<hr />";

        //Textboxes
        TextBox txtFirstName = new TextBox();
        TextBox txtSecondName = new TextBox();

        //FirstName
        txtFirstName.ID = "txtFirstName" + i;
        txtFirstName.Text = "First Name " + i;

        //Second name
        txtSecondName.ID = "txtSecondName" + i;
        txtSecondName.Text = "Last Name " + i;

        buttonPanel.Controls.Add(hrline);
        pnlteacherExp.Controls.Add(txtFirstName);
        pnlteacherExp.Controls.Add(txtSecondName);
        pnlteacherExp.Controls.Add(hrline);
    }
}
```

Save button to save to database:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crud_connection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "Store_proc";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        sqlConnection1.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffPayroll", "payroll_num");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", ??);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", ??);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
    }                
}
```

Comment: Dynamic controls are lost after postback. If you want to access values from the controls you created, you will need to create them latest in the page's `Load` event. For your case, you'd probably want to store the input value in session after the button has been clicked, then reload the page. Then, in the `Load` event, check for values stored in session and create the textboxes.

Comment: Or you could also reload the page with a query string instead of storing the input value in session. So you'd redirect to something like `~/MyPage.aspx?NoOfRowsToCreate=3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the post parametres using the `Request.Form`.

The posted parametres are use the `name` value of the rendered html element, or the `UniqueID` on server side, but because you can not set the `UniqueID` on server side, and because you make them dynamically, probably the `name` is rendered the same as the `id`, at least on my tests, and the line will be as:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", 
       Request.Form["txtFirstName" + i.ToString()]);
```

To clarify, normally you need to do this `Request.Form[control.UniqueID]` to get the posted value, but because you do not have the `control` because you make it dynamically and is not there any more, the next is to get the post value with the posted name, so the posted name is this one `"txtFirstName" + i.ToString()` the way you makes them.

relative:
[asp.net request.form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050677/asp-net-request-form/11050754#11050754)
[Accessing control client name and not ID in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763557/accessing-control-client-name-and-not-id-in-asp-net/5763632#5763632)
[Get info about Http Post field order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849075/get-info-about-http-post-field-order/2849782#2849782)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
   TextBox txtFirstName = Controls.FindControl(string.Format("txtFirstName{0}", i)) as TextBox;
   string name = txtFirstName.Text;
```

You can browse through this link to see how you can retain state of the dynamically created control: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i

Comment: Do you know the using statement for this? It cant find the FindControl bit thanks

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my code a bit. Please try it again.